# change color ramp hue using nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, color

i was hoping someone could tell me how to change the color of a color ramp using other connected nodes.

[image: simple colorramp node]
[image]

the second image does it almost right but the color of the whites from the color ramp are only half as strong as they should be. what im trying to do is to change the hue of the white values of the color ramp to a selected color using other attached nodes. the desired effect would be similar to simply changing the white stop of the color ramp to a desired color. but i need the color to be accessible from a group node which is why i cant simply do that.

Comment: Connect the ColorRamp output to the Mix node's "Fac", and assign the two colors of the Mix node.

Comment: i feel so stupid lmao. thank you oh wise one for the knowledge now bestowed to me.